# fetch_param when you only know a portion of the param name

Tags: ee2, add-on-development, plugin

I'm working on extending the external_entries plugin to support a SQL LIKE clause, using the "searchlike" param that was [mentioned here](http://engaging.net/docs/external-entries):

As and example if I wanted to find all rows of an external table in that had a date of 2013 I would use the param searchlike:date="2013%".

Is there a way to use `fetch_param` (or something akin to it) with a param name that you only know the beginning of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The full array of tag params is stored at $EE->TMPL->tagparams. So you can grab them like so:

```
// Get the EE instance
$EE = get_instance();

// Get all of the current tag params
$all_params = $EE->TMPL->tagparams;
```

From there you can loop through and find all of the params that begin with “search:” like this:

```
// Find all of the search:xyz params
$search_params = array();

foreach ($all_params as $name => $value)
{
    // Does this param name start with "search:"?
    if (strncmp($name, 'search:', 7) === 0)
    {
        // Chop off "search:" and save it
        $search_target = substr($name, 7);
        $search_params[$search_target] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly how I do it.

Comment: Cool, that's perfect!